# Arbitrary constants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Consider the linear system
>   $$\begin{cases}
>     x + 2y + 3z = 4 \\
>     x + ky + 4z = 6 \\
>     x + 2y + (k + 2)z = 6,
> \end{cases}$$
>   where $k$ is an arbitrary constant.
>
> For what values of $k$ does the system have a unique solution?

I know for this I have to put it in a matrix, but I am having a problem solving the matrix can someone please help me understand how to go about doing this?

I have tried many times to solve this, but I just cant get an idea on how to do it.

Comment: By "eyeballing" the determinant, you can see that it equals some quadratic in $k$, so there are at most 2 values $k$ cannot be. But $k=1$ makes the first and third equations the same (with different RHS), while $k=2$ makes the second and third equations the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform Gaussian elimination on the augmented matrix:
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & k & 4 & 6 \\
1 & 2 & k+2 & 6
\end{array}\right]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
0 & k-2 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & k-1 & 2 
\end{array}\right]
&&\begin{aligned} R_2&\gets R_2-R_1 \\ R_3&\gets R_3-R_1\end{aligned}
\end{align}
If $k=2$, the system has infinitely many solutions (the last column is not a pivot column). If $k\ne1$, the system has no solution (the last column is a pivot column). In all other cases it has a single solution.

Answer (score 1):

We have: $(3) - (1)$ gives: $(k-1)z = 2$, and $(2) - (1)$ gives: $(k-2)y + z = 2\implies (k-1)(k-2)y + (k-1)z = 2(k-1) = 2k-2\implies (k-1)(k-2)y+2= 2k-2\implies (k-1)(k-2)y = 2k-4 $. Also $(3) - (2)$ yields: $(k-2)z +(2-k)y = 0\implies (k-2)(z-y) = 0\implies k = 2$ or $y = z$. So if $k = 2$, the system has infinite solutions. So $k \neq 2$, then $y = z$. But if $k = 1$, then $0\cdot y = -2$ contradition. Thus $k \neq 1$, and $ y = z = \dfrac{2}{k-1}\implies x = 4 - 2y- 3z = 4-5y= 4- \dfrac{10}{k-1}= \dfrac{4k-14}{k-1}$,and this is unique solution in $(x,y,z)$. In summary, $k \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1,2\}$ for the system to have a unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

multiplying the first equation by $-1$ and adding to the second we get
$$ky-2y+z=2$$
multplying the first equation by $-1$ and adding to the third we get
$$(k+2)z-3z=2$$
from herfe we can compute $z$
$$z=\frac{2}{k-1}$$
if $k=1$ we have no Solutions.
then we compute $y$: $$ky-2y+\frac{2}{k-1}=2$$
simplifying this we get
$$y(k-2)=2\frac{k-2}{k-1}$$
can you finish?